# How to change a value through a method?

Tags: c++, function, variables

So, I have a method that I want to pass in a variable, and have that variable changed, like this:

```
// Not this:
x = addNumber(5, x);

// Like this:
addNumbers(5, x);
```

But how would I do that? I want to make it change a variable without returning a value. What do I do?

Comment: Pass by reference. How have you declared addNumbers()?  You will need to modify it, most likely.

Comment: I declared it. No compiler errors. I just want to pass by reference. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass it by reference:

```
void addNumber(int n, int& x)
{
    x += n;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    addNumber(5, x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void addNumbers(int x, int& y) {
  y += x;  // y will have the value of x+y when you return from this method
}
```

The ampersand character in the `int& y` allows it to be passed as a reference, meaning you can change the value of the variable inside the method, and that change will persist upon method return.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference:

```
inline void addNumber(const int val, int& dst) {
    dst += val;
}
```

and somewhere:

```
int x = 7;
addNumber(5, x);
```